# .env variable are not accessible in application

Tags: laravel, variables, environment-variables

Some time .env variable are not available in my controller, even I used env(variable name) or getenv(variable name) in my controller, but getting the blank value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your configuration is not cached. When it is cached, the `.env` file is not loaded at all. You can clear the configuration cache with `php artisan config:clear`.

Please also be aware that using `env('var')` outside of configuration files is considered bad practice because it prevents you from using `php artisan config:cache`. Caching the configuration will only replace `env('var')` calls within configuration files and shrink all configuration files into one file, but it will not replace calls in controllers or other files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with variable name in quotes. That's works

Ex:

in laravel controller

```
env('TEST_VARIABLE')
```

in laravel blade

```
{{ env('TEST_VARIABLE') }}
```